# CSS enlarge on hover breaks the design

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm battling with CSS syntax and I'm trying to apply it to the next code:

```
/*========== HOME ==========*/
.home{
    &__img{
        width: 300px;
        border-radius: .5rem;
        justify-self: center;
    }
}
```

An on hover image effect: To enlarge the image, let's say with the next code

```
.zoom {
  padding: 50px;
  transition: transform .2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.zoom:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(2.5); 
}
```

my HTML div code:

```
 <div class="services__content">
     <img src="assets/img/image.jpg" class="zoom" class="home__img">
     <h3 class="menu__name">some text</h3>
     <span class="menu__detail">some text</span>
     <span class="menu__prices"></span>
 </div>
```

Problem:

That when I hover over the image, the enlarged image doesn't cover the images or other objects near and just goes beneath them while being enlarged, all other objects such as images, text, superposition on top of that enlarged image, and the effect are like the hovered image acts as a background for them...which is incorrect for me.

Desired effect:

When hovering over an image, and when it does enlarge, it should cover the nearest objects and not act as a background for them, then when your cursor goes to another image, it gets back to its original size, and the next one is enlarged.

If someone can help me out, I'd appreciate it. It seems everything I do, doesn't work and just keeps going behind. Will keep on searching and trying to experiment with it meanwhile.

Thanks!

Comment: Set this image as a `background-image` on the div and it will solve your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make the div not expand its size when the image is hovered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71228712/how-to-make-the-div-not-expand-its-size-when-the-image-is-hovered)

Comment: @カメロン thank you for the answers. But does that mean, I will have to do the same process and set each image (i have like 30 images) that need such effect in that div.

Comment: Yes, you would have to set the image as a background-image on each div separately. You can try looking into Bootstrap and use the gallery method as seen [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71256063/adding-zoom-in-effect-to-a-bootstrap-gallery). It depends on exactly what the extent you are trying to do is.

Comment: @カメロンmaybe there is a way to just add it inside a css file but inside a section class (the hover effect) so then if there is any image inside that section class with hover, they will have such effect, or that wont work out? :)