# Adding zoom in effect to a bootstrap gallery

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, hover, bootstrap-5

I'd like to make a gallery with bootstrap which looks like this:
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/gallery/

Everything worked, but I wanted to add a hover effect to these pictures, so I put them all in separate containers, which does the trick, but now the pictures aren't lining up anymore, because some are horizontal and others vertical :/
Has anyone an idea to fix this issue?
Here's the code of my project :

https://codepen.io/emmlll/pen/zYPLWxr

```css
.img-gallery {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-gallery img {
  transition: all 1.3s ease;
}

.img-gallery:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<head>

  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="event.js"></script>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script>
    AOS.init();
  </script>
</head>

<div class="col-xl-12" id="gallery">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-lg-0 ">
      <div class="img-gallery">
        <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/large-green-cactus-plant-in-a-yellow-ceramic-vase-picture-id118062993?s=612x612" class="w-100 shadow-1-strong rounded-3 " />

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-lg-0 ">
      <div class="img-gallery ">
        <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/cactus-plant-with-green-leaves-and-shovels-and-small-yellow-thorns-on-picture-id1012417960?s=612x612" class="w-100 shadow-1-strong rounded-3" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-lg-0 ">
      <div class="img-gallery mb-4">
        <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/large-green-cactus-plant-in-a-yellow-ceramic-vase-picture-id118062993?s=612x612" class="w-100 shadow-1-strong rounded-3" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-lg-0 ">
      <div class="img-gallery">
        <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/cactus-plant-with-green-leaves-and-shovels-and-small-yellow-thorns-on-picture-id1012417960?s=612x612" class="w-100 shadow-1-strong rounded-3" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0" style="display:flex">
      <div class="img-gallery">
        <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/large-green-cactus-plant-in-a-yellow-ceramic-vase-picture-id118062993?s=612x612" class="w-100 shadow-1-strong rounded-3 " />

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-lg-0 ">
      <div class="img-gallery">
        <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/cactus-plant-with-green-leaves-and-shovels-and-small-yellow-thorns-on-picture-id1012417960?s=612x612" class="w-100 shadow-1-strong rounded-3" />

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a Bootstrap gallery, you should nest all images for each column in the same one. You had a new column for each image which is what was spacing it out. You'll notice if you inspect the example from your link it is structured like that. Then just nest each image in an `img-gallery` which has the hover effect.

***See below:***

*Edit ~* I wasn't sure if you wanted that masonry-type layout from the listed example. If you do, just add `mb-4` as a class on the images.

```css
.img-gallery {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-gallery img {
  transition: all 1.3s ease;
}

.img-gallery:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<head>

  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="event.js"></script>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script>
    AOS.init();
  </script>
</head>

<div class="col-xl-12" id="gallery">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-lg-0 ">
      <div class="img-gallery">
        <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/large-green-cactus-plant-in-a-yellow-ceramic-vase-picture-id118062993?s=612x612" class="w-100 shadow-1-strong rounded-3 " />
      </div>
      <div class="img-gallery">
        <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/cactus-plant-with-green-leaves-and-shovels-and-small-yellow-thorns-on-picture-id1012417960?s=612x612" class="w-100 shadow-1-strong rounded-3" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-lg-0 ">
      <div class="img-gallery ">
        <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/cactus-plant-with-green-leaves-and-shovels-and-small-yellow-thorns-on-picture-id1012417960?s=612x612" class="w-100 shadow-1-strong rounded-3" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-gallery">
        <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/large-green-cactus-plant-in-a-yellow-ceramic-vase-picture-id118062993?s=612x612" class="w-100 shadow-1-strong rounded-3" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-lg-0 ">
      <div class="img-gallery mb-4">
        <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/large-green-cactus-plant-in-a-yellow-ceramic-vase-picture-id118062993?s=612x612" class="w-100 shadow-1-strong rounded-3" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-gallery">
        <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/cactus-plant-with-green-leaves-and-shovels-and-small-yellow-thorns-on-picture-id1012417960?s=612x612" class="w-100 shadow-1-strong rounded-3" />
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great thanks, but now the hover reacts also to the picture below :( that’s why I added everything in a separate container :/

Comment: @FluffyWaves See edits - easy fix just nest each image in an `img-gallery` individually since that is the div with the `:hover` effect.

Comment: Ahhhh, of course! Thank you so much, have a wonderful day/night! :)